# New questions for different versions or pile them together?

Tags: discussion, tags

This person had their question answered by plugging it in and it works:

- [How do I get a CSL Usb Modem U1-TF to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9761/how-do-i-get-a-csl-usb-modem-u1-tf-to-work)

However a new user just posted because it didn't work on an older version of Ubuntu. So is the right thing to do here to split off a new question tagged with 10.04 instead or do we try to get an answer for 10.04 in the same question and add the version tag?

Keeping in mind that we add 2 new version tags a year and those releases are supported for 18 months and every 2 years we add a tag that is supported for up to 5 years -- so we'll need something that scales.

Kind of baffled this doesn't come up more often.

Comment: Note: with 11.04 the use by default of Unity could make this particularly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time a solution will be version indiscriminate. In my opinion it is *another* question. CSL USB Modem U1-TF doesn't work with 10.04 - as such It's my opinion that it needs to be a new question.

However, we've had such questions where multi-version solutions have been provided - the problem isn't that we can't do this, it's that the original question asker has no vested interest in anything but *their* question and their version of Ubuntu - so it likely won't be maintained very well when ubuntu+3 comes out (or even ubuntu+1)